# Why does the destructor run twice in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

While doing my programming assignments, I seem to be stumbling over basic C++ concepts. I found the bug in my program and it was caused by my destructor running more times than I expected. Here is a code sample demonstrating what I am doing wrong, down to the bare essentials.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int num)
    {
        number = num;
        cout << "A constructed with number " << number << ".\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "A destructed with number " << number << ".\n";
    }
private:
    int number;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A pa)
        : a(pa)
    {
        cout << "B constructor run.\n";
    }
    ~B()
    {
        cout << "B destructor run.\n";
    }
private:
    A a;
};


int main()
{
    A foo(7);
    {
        B bar(foo);
    }
    //Pause the program.
    system("pause");
}
```

What I expect to happen is `A foo(7);` allocates space on the stack for an `A` object named `foo` and call the constructor, passing `7`. It assigns `7` to `number` and prints output indicating the the constructor ran. Now `B bar(foo);` allocates space on the stack for a `B` object named `bar` and calls the constructor, passing `foo` by value, which is just a container for an `int`. The constructor assigns the `A` parameter passed to it to it's own private data member `a`, and prints output to the screen.

Now, when `bar` goes out of scope at the closing curly brace, I expect `bar`'s destructor to be called, which prints output to the screen, then calls the destructor for its data members, namely `A a`. That destructor prints output to the screen, and discards the `int number` that it was containing.

What I expect the output should be:

```
A constructed with number 7.
B constructor run.
B destructor run.
A destructed with number 7.
//Destructors should be called in the reverse order of their construction right?
```

The actual output:

```
A constructed with number 7.
B constructor run.
A destructed with number 7. //This is unexpected.
B destructor run.
A destructed with number 7.
```

What is causing that extra destruction?

Comment: Make noisy copy constructors too.

Comment: Check out the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the destructor of the class called twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627540/why-is-the-destructor-of-the-class-called-twice)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the destructor of the class called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627540/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it comes from member data A a; of class B. I guess your doubt is that why not see any construct output from A, because it's constructed with default copy-ctor for class A, It's better to add one copy-ctor for class A, so that you will see the construct procedure.

```
A(const A& a)
{
     number = a.number;
     cout << "A copy-constructed with number " << number << ".\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `B` constructor takes the `A` object by value, which means that `foo` is copied into the parameter `pa` which then gets copied to the member `a`. The compiler has been able to elide one of the copies (argument to the constructor), but the other one cannot be elided and there you have the second `A` object that get's destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I hate it when people get cute with "foo" and "bar".

But I see two instances of "A" being constructed - one explicitly, the other implicitly by "B".  And two destructors getting invoked.

What's not to like about this picture ;)?

Answer (score 0):

because in class B, there has one member  `A a`
so to destruct B object, first to call its member's destructor.