# Constructor called once but destructor called several times when using of boost::thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, constructor, destructor

I'm using of `boost` library to create a thread in c++ by `boost::thread` class.
I have the following class in which defined a `void routine (int)` as a `boost::thread` routine :

***`A` class :***

```
class A
{
public:
    // Constructor
    A() { cout << "this is constructor" << endl; }

    void routine(int num)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            // do stuffs
            cout << num + i << endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    // Destructor
    ~A() { cout << "this is destructor" << endl; }
};
```

***And `main` function :***

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    myThread = new boost::thread(&A::routine, a, 6);

    myThread->join();

    return 0;
}
```

In the `main` I create an object of `A` and constructor function is call once, but something is wrong. in this situation the `destructor` function should be call just once too, but it called several times and the following result is obtained :

```
this is constructor
this is destructor
this is destructor
this is destructor
this is destructor
this is destructor
this is destructor
this is destructor
6
7
8
9
10
11
this is destructor
this is destructor
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You are not counting the use of the compiler defined copy constructor.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks. My problem solved. I counted the copy constructor and the number of `constructors` and `destructors` are equal...

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Comment: @RSahu but my question is not duplicated like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875381/c-why-does-my-destructor-run-twice

Comment: The question is not but cause of the problem is the same and explanation of the behavior is the same.

Comment: Also see [Why is the destructor of the class called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627540/608639)

Comment: @RSahu but why by calling `boost::thread` one time, create more than one object??? please answer me.

Comment: `boost::thread` constructor takes its argument by value, if you don't want to create copy you could pass params with `boost::ref` , `boost::cref`, these wrap objects into pointer, and no copies are made.