# C++ how to pass 'this' to pointer reference

Tags: c++, argument-passing, this-pointer

i have main class that i like to pass its pointer reference to on of the objects i creating but it gives me error :

> Error 1   error C2664: 'GameController::GameController(GameLayer *&)' :
>   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'GameLayer *const ' to 'GameLayer *&'

what i have in the GameLayer ( the main object )

```
m_pGameController = new GameController(this);
```

and in the GameController i have this constructor

```
GameController(GameLayer*& GameLayer)
{
 setGameLayer(gameLayer); // to GameLayer memeber ) 
}
```

the resone is i need to be able to modify the data in GameLayer from GameController (GUI stuff)

Comment: Why does it need to be a reference?  I'm going to go ahead and bet that it probably doesn't.

Comment: `this` is not a `GameLayer *&`. It's either a `GameLayer *` or a `const GameLayer *`, depending on the constness of the currently running method.

Comment: Also, note that instead of a variable you're using the type name itself in the constructor. `GameController(GameLayer*& GameLayer)` shouldn't it be `GameController(GameLayer*& gameLayer)`

Comment: Please avoid pointers: GameController(GameLayer& GameLayer) and than m_GameController = GameController(*this); - this does not address const correctness

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the type of `this` could be `GameLayer * const` or `const GameLayer * const` depending upon whether the member function is `const` or not. But, it is a `const` pointer.

Having said that, a reference to  a pointer `type *&ref` means indicates that you will be modifying the pointer, the object which it is pointing to.

"Since, this pointer is a constant pointer you cannot assign that to a non-const pointer(GameLayer * p)" in the **context of references**.

In case of references to pointer, you cannot assign to a reference which will modify the value in `this`. You cannot assign it to a reference to a `non-const` pointer(`GameLayer *&p)`, but you can assign a reference to a `const` pointer i.e. `GameLayer *const &p`.

So, changing the constructor to `GameController(GameLayer * const & gameLayer)` should work.
But I don't see any use of it here currently.

And if you're calling from a `const` member function then `this` has the type `const *const` so you will have to change it to `GameController(const GameLayer * const & gameLayer)`.

Comment: *"Since, this pointer is a constant pointer you cannot assign that to a non-const pointer(GameLayer * p)"* -- Yes, you can.

Comment: Specifically: the set of all things that can be used to initialize `GameLayer *` is identical to the set of all things that can be used to initialize `GameLayer *const`. The `const` in that location only affects whether you can assign to `p`, it doesn't affect what you can initialize it with. The difference between initializing `GameLayer *&` and initializing `GameLayer *const&` is as you say.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, I agree. But isn't what is written above true?

Comment: @Uchia: No, what you wrote is not all true. The part that is not true is, "Since, this pointer is a constant pointer you cannot assign that to a non-const pointer(GameLayer * p) but you can assign it to a const pointer (GameLayer * const p)."

Comment: @SteveJessop: Could you please point out, I am unable to get you.

Comment: @UchiaItachi: I'm sorry, I cannot explain it in any other terms. There is a sentence in your answer that is false. I have quoted that sentence to you, so that you know which one I'm talking about. You agree with my comment in which I describe what is false about it. I simply cannot understand what it is that you don't get.

Answer (score 5):

i don't know why are you using `*&` but it'll work fine if you do:

```
GameController(GameLayer* GameLayer)
{
 setGameLayer(gameLayer); // to GameLayer memeber ) 
}
```

Comment: Depends. If the method that performs `new GameController(this)` is `const` (which seems to be true in the questioner's case), then `this` will be a `const GameLayer *` and the constructor of `GameController` (or an overload) should take a `const GameLayer *`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The method is not `const` in the questioner's case. You can tell from the error message.

Comment: @interjay, aye, but is `GameLayer *const` not supposed to be the same as `const GameLayer *`? I'll have to look that up.

Comment: `this` can be of type `GameLayer * const` or `const GameLayer * const`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, they are not the same. `GameLayer *const` means that the pointer is `const` but the value it points to is not.

Comment: @interjay, [yup](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constptrconst.html), Itachi and you are right. Guess I need more tea.

Answer (score 1):

' this'  is a pointer constant so you can pass it as reference or const reference.

```
 m_pGameController = new GameController(*this);

 GameController(GameLayer& GameLayer) {}
```

Comment: You don't pass `this` as a reference, you pass `*this` as a reference. Which is perfectly valid, but not what the question is about.

Comment: Agree but I used reference because it is more C++

Answer (score 1):

"No Idea For Name"'s answer is almost certainly what you need, but for additional information the reason your code doesn't work is that `GameLayer*&` doesn't just mean, "I can modify the GameLayer object referred to by the argument value I receive", it means "I am passed a reference to a pointer to a GameLayer object I can modify, and also I can use this reference to change the pointer value itself".

So for example:

```
void foo(GameLayer *&layerptr) {
    layerptr = new GameLayer();
}

void main() {
    GameLayer *ptr = 0;
    std::cout << (void*)ptr << "\n";
    foo(ptr);
    std::cout << (void*)ptr << "\n";
}
```

The value of the `ptr` variable in `main` has changed. That's what pass-by-non-const-reference is for, and so you do not need pass-by-non-const-reference here. Either pass a pointer to a `GameLayer` object (type `GameLayer*`) or a reference (type `GameLayer&`), not both.

The reason it is not valid to pass `this` to a function that accepts `GameLayer*&` is that `this` is not a variable and it cannot be assigned to -- in C++ jargon it is not an lvalue and so you can't take an lvalue reference to it. `this` tells you what object the current member function is being called on, and you cannot suddenly decide that your member function will from now on be operating on a different object.