# Why is the destructor of an exception called twice?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyError : public runtime_error
{
    public:
        MyError(string mess = "");
        ~MyError(void);
    };

    MyError::MyError(string mess) : runtime_error(mess)
    {
        cout << "MyError::MyError()\n";
    }

    MyError::~MyError(void)
    {
        cout << "MyError::~MyError\n";
    }


int main(void)
{
    try {
        throw MyError("hi");
    }
    catch (MyError& exc) {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }

    cout << "goodbye\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Which prints the following:

```
MyError::MyError()
MyError::~MyError
hi
MyError::~MyError
goodbye
```

Why is the destructor of the exception (**~MyError()**) called twice?

I assumed that throw creates a new object, but I do not understand why the class destructor is called.

Comment: Your exception gets copied when it's thrown.  1st destructor is from the `try` block, 2nd is the copied exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the destructor of the class called twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627540/why-is-the-destructor-of-the-class-called-twice)

Comment: The exception temporary is copied, but this copy may be elided. If it is, you'll only see one destructor call: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1e5773144874712

Comment: @wheatin That question is about the destructor of an object added to a collection, I don't think it's the same.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: BTW you should better catch exceptions using a `const` reference: `catch (const MyError& exc) {`, it's commonly appreciated best practice.

Comment: @NathanOliver Microsoft Visual C++ (2013)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you instrument the exception's copy or move constructor, you'll find it's called once before the handler. There's a temporary *exception object* into which the thrown expression is copied/moved, and it is this *exception object* to which the reference in the handler will bind. C++14 15.1/3+

So the execution resulting from your code looks something like this (pseudo-C++):

```
// throw MyError("hi"); expands to:
auto tmp1 = MyError("hi");
auto exceptionObject = std::move(tmp1);
tmp1.~MyError();
goto catch;

// catch expands to:
MyError& exc = exceptionObject;
cout << exc.what() << endl;

// } of catch handler expands to:
exceptionObject.~MyError();

// normal code follows:
cout << "goodbye\n";
```

Comment: Is a c++ compiler permitted to perform copy elision in this case? If so, why doesn't it?

Comment: @Random832 Yes, copy elision is allowed in this case. Why VS doesn't do it is anyone's guess - maybe the OP's optimisation flags don't make it do so?

Answer (score 4):

Because your compiler is failing to elide the copy from the temporary to the exception object managed by the exception handling mechanism.

Conceptually, `MyError("hi")` creates a temporary, which will be destroyed at the end of the statement (before the exception can be handled). `throw` copies the thrown value somewhere else, where it will persist until after the exception has been handled. If the thrown value is a temporary, then a decent compiler should elide the copy and initialise the thrown value directly; apparently, your compiler didn't do that.

My compiler (GCC 4.8.1) does a rather better job:

```
MyError::MyError()
hi
MyError::~MyError
goodbye
```

Answer (score 3):

Your exception is being copied. If you instrument the copy ctor, you can see this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyError : public runtime_error
{
public:
    MyError(MyError const &e) : runtime_error("copy") { std::cout << "Copy MyError"; }
    MyError(string mess = "");
    ~MyError(void);
};

MyError::MyError(string mess) : runtime_error(mess) {
    cout << "MyError::MyError()\n";
}

MyError::~MyError(void) {
    cout << "MyError::~MyError\n";
}

int main(void) {
    try {
        throw MyError("hi");
    }
    catch (MyError& exc) {
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }

    cout << "goodbye\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
MyError::MyError()
Copy MyError
MyError::~MyError
copy.what()
MyError::~MyError
goodbye
```