# Why is the destructor of the class called twice? shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, destructor, undefined-behavior, object-lifetime

```
 class Class {
 public:
     Class()  {std::cout << "Constructor" << '\n';}
     ~Class() {std::cout << "Destructor" << '\n';}
 }; 

 int main() {
     std::cout<<"\nNew shared_ptr:\n";
     Class C;
     std::shared_ptr<Class> ptr(&C);
 }
```

After running I have:

```
New shared_ptr: 
Constructor 
Destructor 
Destructor
```

Why is that? Why is the destructor called twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627540/why-is-the-destructor-of-the-class-called-twice

Comment: It could be but I don't know if this is the same case with shared_ptr as with vector

Comment: @apk How is that a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Raw pointers in C++ stores the address of the object (point to the object), whereas smart pointers in C++ act as a wrapper around the raw pointer with automatic delete feature.

Though smart pointers usually do not replicate raw objects but in your case you are passing the address of local `C` as a parameter, therefore the copy of `C` gets stored in the heap.

**To sum up `Class C;` uses stack memory whereas `std::shared_ptr<Class> ptr(&C);` uses heap memory.**

At the end of the `main()` function, the `C` goes out of scope, therefore destructor is called.

Then the shared pointer deletes its object in the heap automatically, so its corresponding destructor is called.

**Therefore two destructor.**

Comment: There's no copy. `ptr` tries to take ownership of `C`, which is already owned by `main`. A double destruction of the same object and undefined behaviour ensue.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a raw pointer to a `std::shared_ptr`, without also using a custom deleter, means that the `shared_ptr` implementation will `delete` that pointer value after no more `shared_ptr` own the pointer.  In your example, this happens at the end of `main` when `ptr` is destroyed, so it attempts to `delete` a pointer equal to `&C`.  This is only valid for a pointer that came from a `new` expression.  But the pointer did not come from `new`; it's just the address of a local variable defined in `main`.  So this is undefined behavior.