# shared_ptrs being deleted twice

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr, stdvector

I want to store shared pointers to the `Object` class in a vector:

Test code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;   // only for brevity

class Object
{
public:
  int n;
  Object(int n) : n(n) { cout << "Object("  << n <<")\n"; }
  ~Object() { cout << "~Object(" << n << "))\n"; n = 0xdddddddd; }

};

void Test()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Object> p1(make_shared<Object>(Object(123)));
  std::vector<shared_ptr<Object>> v;

  cout << "before push_back\n";
  v.push_back(std::make_shared<Object>(Object(2)));
  v.push_back(p1);
  cout << "after push_back\n";

  cout << "Vector content:\n";
  for (auto& p : v)
    cout << "  " << p->n << "\n"; ;
}

int main()
{
  Test();
  cout << "after Test()\n";
}
```

The output is

```
Object(123)
~Object(123))        <<< why is the destructor called here?
before push_back
Object(2)
~Object(2))          <<< why is the destructor called here?
after push_back
Vector content:
  2
  123
~Object(2))          <<< destructor called again 
~Object(123))
after Test()
```

I don't understand why the destructors are called twice.

OTOH the vector content is what I want.

Comment: `Object(123)` and `Object(2)` creates *temporary* objects that will be destructed.

Comment: You should print `this` in your `cout`'s to get a better view of what is deleted.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but why do I see _one_ contructor call and _two_ desctructor calls for each object? Shouldn't be there _two_ constructor calls?

Comment: Because the temporary objects will be *copied* (or moved) using the copy-constructor (or move-constructor). You don't implement those. And even if you implement them, the compiler can [*elide*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (not call) them.

Comment: When logging constructor/destructor, don't forget the copy and move ones.

Comment: Duplicate? [Why is the destructor of the class called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627540/why-is-the-destructor-of-the-class-called-twice)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I don't understand why the destructors are called twice.

Because of creating unnecessary temporary objects here:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Object> p1(make_shared<Object>(Object(123)));
                                               ^^^
                                               temporary object
```

and here:

```cpp
v.push_back(std::make_shared<Object>(Object(2)));
                                     ^^^
                                     temporary object
```

It should instead be

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Object> p1(make_shared<Object>(123));
```

and

```cpp
v.push_back(std::make_shared<Object>(2));
```

**Why?**

Because [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::shared_ptr using args as the parameter list for the constructor of T. And in your code, you are making one extra object which immediately gets destroyed, thus calling the destructor.

**Why don't you see `Object(int n);` constructor being called for temporary object?**

`Object(int n);` constructor is indeed being called for the temporary object, but since the object held by the `std::shared_ptr` is created through copy constructor (so, by copying the temporary object) you won't see call to `Object(int n);` for it but call to `Object(Object const& other);`.

In the [demo](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BPbrvc281QeHQUwAKkCCBmMdiaRCQCAFAgMph0AB9LwEFZzf2rKZeTgQIzMADWmHXy9XkN3hYIqwg6c41yryoHyfBBHQi8WqhIjyvE4Ny3HcdD3XI1ggqZ5mpGFNjJL0SyFSRXBoE4Dx%2BBB12cUFT1VGt43feDoJdPFl2w3CIAXEAT3PS8VyAx5wOwR87wgaMq1g4j5lIzCKOQU8IEPN8cQQvpvQVPNhWYKgCDcDDyJwgT8LjSQuJpRDy2QgA1JYSBNegtAIElY1rUSpjQqYIGYPlUHNA8WWg5UPzEnMtOLZCkK8ABaVYGzDCt41MwjuXUns4MZE87BnPtzMnZoZyI1yJN9aTZPk%2BLp2rVSwp1IYelYEAhhVIZSFMIZ1lK1AioVGQ5HBPoBn2UZOFK4yKvynpTxAFVJBdMxckxdZMRVTFOAADnWTgVTMWahCK7hSvKyrSGqoZSoUEB1lIdrKp6OBYBgRAUFQIwvDwdgyAoCA0DOi7qmABQAS8ZcrVIKgLrk4hNogZwipW5w7AyN4ita0hbueegkVoVgQY60gsBPUR2H%2B0r8BOYpFk2%2BHMBbIo%2BWGFaKWUVGhDwZxiGBvQsFBtriDwIxaZ6Gh6CYNgOB4fhBGEUQUDkOQyecTbIB6VAtwCbHvIhRsJDqmQEg2wpig0CArAaUxPCsCoYjiQQfD8FJAn0HI9fCQ3taqeICmSEoWnVwQkiWW2ygtjoreaMp7cSFpXd1zgegURrBi4AqipKsrSbWltxrMbyzG4KZgGQZArO3AxaFPZkIFwQh9Ja0gpj0O7LqFXJ/cL/mZDa1Gq1IbrBpdFV5qGRbSEZlVtuWqqio2radpr0gDuO8S8QIchKFu87LsENdc6tlnGBYFHOYAd0prwmeb8Ou9WoqWqmFfCAQKZo9j%2BPE%2BT1PiHTzPq462ubWYLB3AzZvW/bzvI57xQ%2B92zq65ANwTELpchmEkAATkkNwSQ41ODgPGtwXIuReCFSGLkJaX91r93vqHIYkgMHwzWnfPaPRFjfQCIAoAA%3D), you can see first `Object(int n);` constructor being called for the temporary object and then the call to copy constructor `Object(Object const& other);` for the actual object being referenced by the `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: _" And in your code, you are making one extra object which immediately gets destroyed, thus calling the destructor"_: OK, I get this, but why don't I see the __construction__ of the temporary object?

Comment: @Jabberwocky because copy constructor is being called. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/CHXkff)

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have updated my answer. Let me know if you have additional questions

Comment: @Jabberwocky, you *do* see the construction of the temporary.  What you're not seeing is the copy-construction of the shared object.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have to destroy the temporary values.

The `std::make_shared` function takes any amount of parameter and construct a value of the given type with it.

You construct a `Object` and pass it to `std::make_shared`, which in its turn construct a value using `new`. Then, the temporaries are destroyed. Later, the shared pointers also are destroyed.

Simply change this in your code:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> p1(make_shared<Object>(123));

// ...  

v.push_back(std::make_shared<Object>(2));
```

And you'll see only one destructor for each values.